# lxml.etree.ElementTree mangles diacritics

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, lxml, diacritics

An alternative title could be *Why does lxml.etree.ElementTree.write not believe the encoding I specify?*

Transforming some json response into some XML dialect with Python 3.6. The json is proper utf-8, all I do with the data is wrap it in XML-tags using `lxml.builder`.

I want to be able to check the xml result in a browser, so I use the `write` method from `lxml.etree.ElementTree` to make an xml file that I open with Firefox (or Chrome, or IE or Edge, makes no difference).

Below is some test code, using a string with diacritics instead of the json response. This works fine. Note `xml_declaration=True` to notify the browser of the encoding.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from lxml import etree as ET
from lxml.builder import E          # E *is* ElementMaker()

s = 'Björn Nøsflùgl in Israël'      # ö = c3 b6, ø = c3 b8, ù = c3 b9, ë = c3 ab

xml = E.myXML(E.name(s))            # <class 'lxml.etree._Element'>
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)          # <class 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>

tree.write(open('1.xml', 'wb'), xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
# xml declaration says 'UTF-8', Firefox renders correctly
```

However, when I do the same with the json response, diacritics get mangled.

**EDIT:** The following demonstrates the problem (in Windows / Python 3.6 virtual environment).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  

import requests  
import json 
from lxml import etree as ET  
from lxml.builder import E  

URL = '''http://vocab.getty.edu/sparql.json?query=SELECT ?term WHERE {?subject luc:term "löss*"; xl:prefLabel [dct:language gvp_lang:nl; xl:literalForm ?term]}'''

gvp_json = requests.get(URL).json()

with open('gvp_response.json', 'w') as f:           
    f.write(str(gvp_json))

for record in gvp_json['results']['bindings']: 
    term = record['term']['value']  # .encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
    print(term)    

xml = E.myXML(E.term(term)) 
tree = ET.ElementTree(xml)          
tree.write(open('1.xml', 'wb'), xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

If I append `.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` to the `term` clause as indicated in the comment, the problem is solved. But why that should be necessary?

**EDIT 2:** Meanwhile, from [this old issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue8047#msg100902), I learned a possible workaround, that is platform-independent or even machine-independent:

```
import locale 
...

myencoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()  
for record in gvp_json['results']['bindings']: 
    s = record['term']['value']
    if myencoding == 'utf-8':
        term = s
    else:
        term = s.encode(myencoding).decode('utf-8') 

    print(term) 
    ...
```

It sure ain't pretty, but it works. And it doesn't `encode().decode()` unnecessarily.

Explanation - please CMIIW: `print()` needs to assume some encoding, has no way of deducing it from the data itself, and therefor resorts to `locale.getpreferredencoding()` when printing to the console.

But why does `lxml.etree.ElementTree.write()` interpret the data as being cp1252-encoded *when I specify* it's utf-8? IMHO that `encode().decode()` shouldn't be necessary at all.

Any learned comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "when I do the same with the json response, diacritics get mangled". How do they get mangled? How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: @mzjn Good point, thank you. I added some code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I can reproduce this. It says "lÃ¶ssgrunden", which is what you get if "lössgrunden", encoded in UTF-8, is interpreted as being encoded in CP1252 or Latin-1.

Comment: @mzjn Exactly. But I don't understand why this happens, nor what causes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the webserver is not returning correct HTTP headers for the content it delivers.

If you check what headers are returned, you can see `ISO-8859-1` (see `Content-Type` header):

```
$ python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = '''http://vocab.getty.edu/sparql.json?query=SELECT ?term WHERE {?subject luc:term "löss*"; xl:prefLabel [dct:language gvp_lang:nl; xl:literalForm ?term]}'''
>>>
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
>>> r.apparent_encoding
'ISO-8859-9'
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(dict(r.headers))
{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="sparql.json"',
 'Content-Language': 'en-US',
 'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-results+json;charset=ISO-8859-1',
 'Date': 'Wed, 04 Apr 2018 09:55:40 GMT',
 'Link': '<http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1.0/>; rel="license"',
 'Set-Cookie': 'BIGipServerForest=587573440.45165.0000; path=/; Httponly, '
               'TS01e0ec9b=01612fcdbaa1d82ab58469a933fdc88755f6f4d7323361b3f59734f898a9c7014e66f7c5cbf39c733fd24dc4e8817f73daf98f5aba52069337bdae2569cd6dbf2a6f05579c; '
               'Path=/',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
```

And the text is indeed unreadable:

```
>>> r.text
'{\n  "head" : {\n    "vars" : [ "term" ]\n  },\n  "results" : {\n    "bindings" : [ {\n      "term" : {\n        "xml:lang" : "nl",\n        "type" : "literal",\n        "value" : "lÃ¶ssgronden"\n      }\n    } ]\n  }\n}'
```

python-requests tried its best to decode the response body and used `ISO-8859-1`.
See [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) for what happens.

> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on
>   HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take
>   advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the
>   encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing
>   this property.

The thing is that you know that the response is UTF-8 encoded, so you can force it:

```
>>> # force encoding used when accessing r.text
... # see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text
... 
>>> r.encoding = 'utf-8'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> r.text
'{\n  "head" : {\n    "vars" : [ "term" ]\n  },\n  "results" : {\n    "bindings" : [ {\n      "term" : {\n        "xml:lang" : "nl",\n        "type" : "literal",\n        "value" : "lössgronden"\n      }\n    } ]\n  }\n}'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> r.json()
{'head': {'vars': ['term']}, 'results': {'bindings': [{'term': {'xml:lang': 'nl', 'type': 'literal', 'value': 'lössgronden'}}]}}
>>> 
>>> pp(r.json())
{'head': {'vars': ['term']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'term': {'type': 'literal',
                                    'value': 'lössgronden',
                                    'xml:lang': 'nl'}}]}}
>>>
```

So forcing the encoding on the `Response` object you get from `requests.get()` will give you nicely decodable JSON data.

Comment: Aha.. Thank you! But then why does writing the json response to the file NOT mangle diacritics?

Comment: Sorry, I did not spot in your question the case where writing the JSON response to file does not mangle diacritics. If you write the raw response (bytes) to file, as a json file, any conformant JSON reader will handle it fine, defaulting to UTF-8 (which the raw response is). The problem is with accessing `r.text` or `r.json()`, which are trying to *decode* the bytes. You can also decode the raw bytes with  `json.loads(r.content)`

Comment: No problem, but I _am_ accessing with `r.json()` and writing as text ('w' not 'wb'). So I'm still a bit puzzled on this particular aspect, but I'm happy with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed at the [Getty support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gettyvocablod/8jvZ-2ZhRj0/SfZpcNXHBwAJ)
It was fixed 10m ago but not yet deployed :-( I've reopened the issue [ITSLOD-460](https://jira.getty.edu/browse/ITSLOD-460) and hope it will be deployed very soon.

Comment: It's now deployed. Thanks guys!